# Case insensitive token matching

Tags: pegkit

Is it possible to set the grammar to match case insensitively.

so for example a rule:

```
checkName = 'CHECK' Word;
```

would match `check name` as well as `CHECK name`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Creator of [PEGKit](https://github.com/itod/pegkit) here.

The only way to do this currently is to use a **Semantic Predicate** in a round-about sort of way:

```
checkName = { MATCHES_IGNORE_CASE(LS(1), @"check") }? Word Word;
```

Some explanations:

- Semantic Predicates are a feature lifted directly from ANTLR. The Semantic Predicate part is the `{ ... }?`. These can be placed anywhere in your grammar rules. They should contain either a single expression or a series of statements ending in a `return` statement which evaluates to a boolean value. This one contains a single expression. If the expression evaluates to **false**, matching of the current rule (`checkName` in this case) will **fail**. A **true** value will allow matching to proceed.
- `MATCHES_IGNORE_CASE(str, regexPattern)` is a convenience macro I've defined for your use in Predicates and Actions to do regex matches. It has a case-sensitive friend: `MATCHES(str, regexPattern)`. The second argument is an `NSString*` regex pattern. Meaning should be obvious.
- `LS(num)` is another convenience macro for your use in Predicates/Actions. It means fetch a **Lookahead String** and the argument specifies how far to lookahead. So `LS(1)` means lookahead by `1`. In other words, "fetch the string value of the first upcoming token the parser is about to try to match".
- Notice that I'm still matching `Word` **twice** at the end there. The first `Word` is necessary for matching  'check' (even though it was already **tested** in the predicate, it was **not matched and consumed**). The second `Word` is for your `name` or whatever.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Just to see if I understand correctly I use the blank Word test as the predicate is what is determining validity. So I am safe to assume if it matches the rule the predicate has passed and the first word matches the predicates regex.

Comment: Basically, yes. Technically, only the `Word` ref is actually **matching** the 'check' word input. But if the Predicate pases, then the `Word` ref match can never fail. So practically speaking, the Predicate is doing the **actual work of recognition**. But the `Word` ref is required to do the **match and consume token**.