# PEGKit Keep trying rules

Tags: pegkit

Suppose I have a rule:

```
myCoolRule:
     Word
     | 'myCoolToken' Word otherRule
```

I supply as input `myCoolToken something else now` it attempts to parse it greedily matches myCoolToken as a word and then hits the `something` and says uhhh I expected EOF, if I arrange the rules so it attempts to match `myCoolToken` first all is good and parses perfectly, for that input.

I am wondering if it is possible for it to keep trying all the rules in that statement to see if any works. So it matches Word fails, comes back and then tries the next rule.

Here is the actual grammar rules causing problems:

```
columnName = Word;
typeName = Word;

//accepts CAST and cast
cast =  { MATCHES_IGNORE_CASE(LS(1), @"CAST") }? Word ;

checkConstraint = 'CHECK' '('! expr ')'!;

expr        = requiredExp optionalExp*;

requiredExp =  (columnName
               | cast '(' expr as typeName ')'
               ... more but not important
optionalExp ...not important
```

The input `CHECK( CAST( abcd as defy) )` causes it to fail, even though it *is valid*

Is there a construct or otherwise to make it verify all rules before giving up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creator of [PEGKit](https://github.com/itod/pegkit) here.

If I understand your question, No, this is not possible. But this is a feature of PEGKit, not a bug.

Your question is related to "determinacy" vs "nondeterminacy". PEGKit is a "deterministic" toolkit (which is widely considered a desirable feature for parsing programming languages).

It seems you are looking for a more "nondeterministic" behavior in this case, but I don't think you should be :).

PEGKit allows you to specify the **priority of alternate options** via the **order in which the alternate options are listed**. So:

```
foo = highPriority
    | lowerPriority
    | lowestPriority
    ;
```

If the `highPriority` option matches the current input, the `lowerPriority` and `lowestPriority` options will **not** get a chance to try to match, even if they are somehow a **"better" match** (i.e. they match more tokens than `highPriority`).

Again, this is related to "determinacy" (`highPriority` is guaranteed to be given primacy) and is widely considered a desirable feature when parsing programming languages.

So if you want your `cast()` expressions to have a higher priority than `columnName`, simply list the `cast()` expression as an option **before** the `columnName` option.

```
requiredExp =  (cast '(' expr as typeName ')'
               | columnName
               ... more but not important
```

---

OK, so that takes care of the ***syntactic*** details. However, if you have higher-level ***semantic*** constraints which can affect parsetime decisions about which alternative should have the highest priority, you should use a **Semantic Predicate**, like:

```
foo = { shouldChooseOpt1() }? opt1
    | { shouldChooseOpt2() }? opt2
    | defaultOpt
    ;
```

[More details on Semantic Predicates here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23165600/34934).