# Match substrings within a PEGKit grammar

Tags: ios, objective-c, pegkit

I am trying to build a grammar that will match on substrings of a word and am not having much. luck. I.e. I try to match on the text 'an' which succeeds, but it fails to match on the first two letters of 'and'

```
expr = phrase*;
phrase = an|text;
an = 'an'
text = Any;
```

I realize this is a basic example.

Comment: Could you please provide code that you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creator of [PEGKit](https://github.com/itod/pegkit) here.

First, I want to say that from this brief description, I suspect that PEGKit may not be the best tool for this job.

PEGKit excels at matching at the **token** level, but is less useful for matching at the **sub-token** (character) level.

If you need to do a lot of purely sub-token matching as described here, Regular Expressions will be a much better solution, and you should use them instead of PEGKit.

However, if you need to check a few sub-token patterns in the context of a larger token-parsing problem, then yes, PEGKit can certainly accomplish that.

---

*So to answer your specific question:*

For this kind of sub-token matching in PEGKit, you should use a **Semantic Predicate**.

Semantic Predicates are described in the brief docs in the [PEGKit readme](https://github.com/itod/pegkit#semantic-predicates). And here is a [previous question on Stack Overflow related to the use of Semantic Predicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23161176/case-insensitive-token-matching).

Semantic Predicates are Objective-C expressions embedded directly in your PEGKit grammars, which return a boolean value to indicate matching should succeed or fail. They are wrapped in a `{ ... }?` construct.

In this case, you could use a Semantic Predicate to match the "prefix" of a matched `Word` token:

```
expr = anPhrase*;
anPhrase = { [LS(1) hasPrefix:@"an"] }? Word;
```

Here, `anPhrase` will only match `Word` tokens which start with `an`.

The `LS(1)` macro (also described in the PEGKit readme) means **"Lookahead String 1"**. It will fetch the string value of the first lookahead token as an `NSString`.

Comment: Thank you Todd. I was coming to the conclusion PEGKit was not the best tool to do the whole job. I am now just using PKTokenizer to get the individual tokens and then regular expressions to handle the sub-tokens.  Thanks for the response.